# Google Play Services Create Turn-based Multiplayer Match Issue

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, multiplayer

**Issue**

I am having **issues** with **creating** a **turn-based multiplayer match** using **google play services** in **unity3D**.

1. **PlayGamesPlatform.Activate() successfully initializes the PlayGamesPlatform**. However, it **doesn't initialize** the **IPlayGamesClient**, or **ITurnBasedMultiplayerClient**.
2. **CreateQuickMatch(...) doesn't ever call OnMatchStarted(...),  parameter in CreateQuickMatch(...)**.
3. Everytime **CreateQuickMatch(...)** is called it sends an **error**, "**NullReferenceException**: Object reference not set to an instance of an object GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.get_TurnBased()"

**Steps Taken**

1. I have **researched** this **issues online**. Certain **forums have noted**, this **issue** is **due to the recent changes** in the **GooglePlay API**. The **solution** was to **downgrade the API** to the **previous revision**. This was **unsuccessful**.
2. **Updating** java and java JDK result **unsuccessful**.

**Links used as reference**

https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/TBMP.md

**Code**

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
      // recommended for debugging:
      PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;

     // Activate the Google Play Games platform
     PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();
}

void OnMatchStarted (bool success, TurnBasedMatch match)
{
     if (success) 
     {
        this.gameMatch = match;
        Debug.Log ("Success");
     } else 
     {
        Debug.Log ("Failed");
     }
} 

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
     if (Input.touchCount > 0 && TouchPhase.Ended == Input.GetTouch (0).phase) 
     {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.TurnBased.CreateQuickMatch (minPlayers, maxPlayers, variant, OnMatchStarted);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to login with an account before you can create a room. Just add the following code after you activate the Google Play Games Platform.

```
Social.localUser.Authenticate(
    (bool success) => { string loginStatus = success ? "Login successful" : "Login failed";
    Debug.Log("Login status: " + loginStatus);
});
```

This function will open a login screen were you can choose with which account to log in. The weird argument in the function is a lambda statement that is called when the authentication process is done. In this case the function either logs `"Login status: Login successful"` or `"Login status: Login failed"`.